# How to perform validation when using add() on many to many relation ships in Django?

Tags: django, many-to-many

i have a Category model with parent/child self relation For primary category and sub categories :

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=100)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category", verbose_name=_("categories"))

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child_set')
```

i need to prevent orphans, to prevent this kind of errors (in admin web interface)

```
c_parent = Category(name='Restaurant')
c_parent.save()

c_child = Category(name="Japanese restaurant", parent=c_parent)
c_child.save()

place1 = Place (name="Planet sushi")
place1.save()
place1.categories.add(c_parent)
place1.categories.add(c_child)
```

So now we have a new Place called "Planet sushi", it's a Restaurant (root category), and a Japanese Restaurant (sub category)

but i want to prevent this kind of things :

```
place2 = Place (name="Tokyofood")
place2.save()

place2.categories.add(c_child)
```

because parent is not set, or is not the correct parent category

where can i do form validation for the admin ? and other forms (because any user can add a new place and will have to choose correct categories for)

Comment: i've updated my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 6):

Use [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) and more specifically the [m2m_changed](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) signal.

Take time to read the doc as signals are not easy to get, and the `m2m_changed` is the most complicated as it's one signal for everything that appends to the m2m relationship.

Basically what you want to check if action is `pre_add`, then raise a ValidationError if the category parent doesn't match your requirements.

Take some time on checking what is `sender` and `instance`, espacially since it changes according to the value of `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

update:

in Place class add this method:

```
def add_cat(self,cat):
    self.categories.add(cat)
    if cat.parent:
        self.add_cat(cat.parent)
```

now instead of using `place1.categories.add(cat)` you can use `place1.add_cat(cat)` and it will automatically add the category, and its parent category, and its parent category and so on. this is not tested, but even if it doesn't work it should get the point across.

Comment: so when adding a new category (or sub cat) we need to re run Place.save() after to check, and add the parent if it hasn't be specified, why not .. not looking perfectly clean for me but can help.

i was looking for doing something in Category model, maybe this is cleaner ?

Comment: oh duh. i was only thinking about editing a place and selecting the categories, then saving the place. if you have some form that only adds new categories to a place, it will not hit the save method of the place object.